# Custom Lucene Standard Analyzer to accept a set of words to filter while indexing

Tags: java, lucene, analyzer, standardanalyzer

I am using the apache.Lucene:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
     <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
     <version>8.10.1</version>          
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
     <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
     <version>8.10.1</version>          
</dependency>
```

I want to make a customAnalyzer in Lucene where in its core will use the StandAnalyzer and also will have accept a set of words to filter out as well while indexing.

I can make a customanalyzer by extending the Analyzer but how do i integrate the StandardAnalyzer in it as well?

Comment: The Lucene [StandardAnalyzer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_10_1/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html#StandardAnalyzer-org.apache.lucene.analysis.CharArraySet-) already supports being able to process a custom list of stop words (if that is what you mean by "_accept a set of words to filter out while indexing_"). See the two relevant constructors (one using a `CharArraySet` of stop words; and the other using a `Reader` (e.g. to read a list of stop words from a file).

Comment: Is this list of words the only "customization" you need? If you need more customizations, can you edit your question to show us your code (_I can make a customanalyzer..._) and clarify where specifically it does not meet your needs?